# Using Quartz jobs with pre-created objects

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I'm using Quartz(1.6.6) , and it's a great system , but one things really bugs me - I want to be able to use non - default constructor for my jobs. 
(Yes , I've tried the JobFactory , but I don't like this solution. See below)

Meaning- Instead of :

```
JobDetail jobDetails = new JobDetail(jobUniqueName, JOBS_GROUP,
        CrawlJob.class);
```

I would like to have something that is more similar to the java Executoers:

```
CrawlJob crawlJob = new CrawlJob(something, somethingelse);
JobDetail jobDetails = new JobDetail(jobUniqueName, JOBS_GROUP,
        crawlJob);
```

I've already seen the documentation on the JobFactory , but this feels like a very bad solution . If I have several types of tasks on the same scheduler , the JobFactory will look like an endless case block , and that really doesn't feels right.

Any more ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't be done in quartz. 
This entire framework is written in a C++ mindset ( - not that there's anything wrong with it , some of my best friends... :)